# Recording a sports team's matches - a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, many-to-many

I am new to Ruby on Rails, but I have created a few simple apps in the past. Now I am doing something a little more complex and I am stumped on database design.

I am creating a sports league manager and I need some advice on how the relationship between teams and games is modelled to point me in the right direction. Every time a game is played between two teams, the match is recorded. I'd like to be able to do the following:

1) On a specific team's page, I would like to show a list of matches the team has participated in.

2) I would like to keep a record of each team's wins, losses, and ties to show on a league standings page.

On point #1 I figured this would be a many-to-many relationship, that is, a Team has many Matches, and a Match has many Teams (well, just two actually). The point I am a bit stumped on is how and where to store the stats for each team. Where do I keep the wins/losses/ties? Are they part of the Team table? If so, if I was to have a page with team standings showing each teams w/losses/ties, how would I get that information?

Comment: I'm thinking on this and I'll post an answer soon. It's definitely an interesting case because while you do have a many-to-many relationship on the surface, it doesn't really fit the mold. I think there's an argument for an intermediary table.

Comment: If you're recording the result of each game, then the wins/losses/ties are implicitly in your database, so you probably don't need to store that data explicitly because you can recalculate it as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

*This isn't really finished, but maybe this will help you or someone else get the ball rolling here.*

I'm focusing on just how to structure the relationship between Teams and Matches. At least part of the solution lies in using a polymorphic association, I believe, and part of it would perhaps be a self join. I swear it's right in front of me and I'm not seeing it.

Taking baby steps here, assuming you have a table like this for your Matches table…

```
  id   |   home_team_id  |  away_team_id  |  home_team_score  |  away_team_score
```

You can set that up in your models with these associations:

```
class Match
  belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => :team
  belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => :team
end

class Team
  has_many :home_matches, :foreign_key => :home_team_id, :class_name => :matches
  has_many :away_matches, :foreign_key => :away_team_id, :class_name => :matches
end
```

The obvious problem there is that there are two relationships when there really should only be one. That's why I think a polymorphic association can help, but this is sort of convoluted.

See the Rails guide on [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) and see if that helps you see what I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest against creating a traditional many-to-many relationship here. Instead, you'd have just two tables: `Teams` and `Matches`.

Each team would be identified by a row in `Teams` and would have a unique identifier, such as `TeamId`.

The `Matches` table would the following columns:

- `MatchId` - a synthetic primary key
- `SeasonId` - identifies the season the match took place in
- `HomeTeamId` - the home team
- `VisitngTeamId` - the away team
- `HomeTeamScore`
- `VisitngTeamScore`
- ... *Any other statistics you'd want to keep for an individual match*

I presume you have the notion of home and visiting teams. If not, you can just name these columns `Team1Id` and `Team2Id`, or something along those lines.

> The point I am a bit stumped on is how and where to store the stats for each team. Where do I keep the wins/losses/ties?

The wins, losses, and ties are implicit in the `Matches` table - you can query that to get back a team's record. For instance, the following query returns the wins, loses, and ties for team X:

```
-- Wins
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Matches 
WHERE SeasonID = @SeasonID AND 
    (HomeTeamId = X AND HomeTeamScore > VisitingTeamScore) OR 
    (VisitingTeamId = X AND VisitingTeamScore > HomeTeamScore)

-- Loses
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Matches 
WHERE SeasonID = @SeasonID AND 
    (HomeTeamId = X AND HomeTeamScore < VisitingTeamScore) OR 
    (VisitingTeamId = X AND VisitingTeamScore < HomeTeamScore)

-- Ties
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Matches 
WHERE SeasonID = @SeasonID AND 
    (HomeTeamId = X OR VisitingTeamId = X) 
    AND VisitingTeamScore = HomeTeamScore
```

Even if you wanted to denormalize the data model and store this information for each team, you wouldn't want to do it in the `Teams` table because you may want to know how many wins/losses/ties a team has for a given season. (I presume a team may stick together through multiple seasons. If this is not the case, disregard.)

Comment: This is the easy part of this problem. You threw away the interesting/difficult part when you decided "against creating a traditional many-to-many relationship here". You also circumvented a lot of really smart functionality that is build into Rails/Arel that could potentially be harnessed by a little bit of thinking up front on how to represent this data in a meaningful way.

Comment: @coreyward: Was the objective to come up with an interesting and difficult solution?

Comment: No, it was to assist in modeling the data in a clear, meaningful way within the constraints of the Ruby on Rails framework, if possible. You missed the boat with your straight SQL solution that eschews ActiveRecord and is filled with nasty camelCased columns & variables.

Comment: @coreyward: Ah, I missed the whole Ruby on Rails bit. I read it at the start of the question, but must have glazed over it when formulating my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going off-the-cuff here, but consider:

```
tblTeam
    TeamID
    TeamName
     . . . OtherTeamFields

tblMatch
    MatchID
    MatchDate
    MatchLocationID
     . . . OtherMatchFields

tblTeam_Matches
    TeamID FK on tblTeam.TeamID
    MatchID FK on tblMatchID
    TeamStanding (Win, Loss, Tie)
```

The structure above has some pros and cons. On the pro side, the outcome for each team involved in a match is stored properly with the team's relationship to that match. One can retrieve the results for each team through a range of matches by setting criteria for TeamID and TeamStanding (i.e. "WHERE TeamStanding = "Win").

However, there is a more complex, but probably more scalable and usefull way, where you would define a TeamScore field for tblTeam_Matches. In this case, the Match winner would be determined by a rather difficult series of sub-queries (By difficult, I mean difficult for ME. I am betting there are folks here on SO who could pop a smaple out quickly . . . But it is a bit of a brain-teaser).

I believe the second option would be a more "proper" way to do it, but I messed with puling some version of:

```
StatsQuery:
    TeamName
    TotalMatches
    Wins
    Losses
    Ties
```

I had a difficult time of it. Correlated sub-queries are NOT my strong point (yet).

Anyway, hope that gives you some food for thought . . .

Comment: It probably makes more sense to store actual scores than the standing/outcome. Irrespective of that, the relationship between the tables here isn't well defined, especially in the context of a Rails application (where you can't store additional data in the join table).

Comment: Ahh. Didn't know that abouth the join table in a rails application. Yeah, the scores was my preferred way to approach it, but as I said, the query began to get crazy while trying to find the "elegant" way of determining wins/losses per team within a aggregated recordset. I know it can be done, but my brain is fried at the moment.

Comment: I don't think getting the wins/loss data is problematic at all, especially with straight SQL, regardless of the way it is structured. That's why I focused more on how to represent the relationship in my answer. Once you have the relationship down, the data structure is obvious and you can write the SQL (or AREL statements) to generate reports like you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using following way

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games
    has_many :matches,:through => :games
end

class Matche < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games
    has_many :teams,:through => :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :match
end
```

and if you need to find total matches played by any team then

```
= team.games.count
```

if you need to find total won matches by any team then

```
= team.games.where(:winner => true).count
```